# What is the recommended max size for space occupied by cells of a partition key?

Tags: cassandra

I see the following limits bandied about

2 million cells per partition - is this per key or is it the sum of all the cells for all the rows in that partition ?

100MB partition size max- is this the total space occupied for all the rows with the same partitionkey ?

is there a recommended number of maximum cells in a partition key and a limit on the amount of space occupied by one ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44327243/2320144

Answer (score 0):

Untill my experience into Cassandra, till now I used 8 columns into Partition Key and everything working so smoothly.

For max limit conditions, you can check below link. 
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/refLimits.html

As you didn't mention about which Version of CQL are you using? Please update that, then you may get more accurate information.